# Getting a System.StackOverflowException' error

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, loops

I am Getting this error *An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll* I know you are not supposed to have an infinite loop but its not an infinate loop because it just has too go till it gets a file number that has not been made yet. How can i go about this a better way?

```
private int x = 0;
public string clients = @"F:\Internal Jobs\Therm-Air Files\Program\P-1-2.0\Clients\";
public string tdate = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yy");

public void saveloop()
{
    string path = LoadPO.Text.Substring(0, LoadPO.Text.LastIndexOf("\\"));
    string name = Path.GetFileName(path);
    string t = Convert.ToString(x);

    if (!File.Exists(path + @"\" + name + ".xlsx")) // This Line throws error
    {
        oSheet.SaveAs(path + @"\" + name + "-" + t + ".xlsx");
        string prop = /* snipped for space reasons, just string concats */

        string Combine = string.Empty;
        int b = 0;
        int c = cf.cPanel.Controls.Count;
        string[] items = new string[c];
        foreach (WProduct ewp in cf.cPanel.Controls)
        {
            string item = /* snipped for space reasons, just string concats */
            items[b] = item;
            b += 1;
        }
        Combine = prop + "^<";
        foreach (var strings in items)
        {
            Combine += strings + "<";
        }

        File.WriteAllText(path + @"\" + name + ".txt", Combine);
    }
    else
    {
        x += 1;
        saveloop();

    }
```

Comment: Which line of code throws the stack overflow error?

Comment: I edited the code showing where

Comment: You're probably not showing all the code needed to specifically answer your question. Quite often, this error is a result of something in the contents of a method causing that method to get called recursively. For instance, a method that gets fired when a change event happens, but the code in the method changes that thing causing the event to fire again, or the method explicitly calling itself, but not handling the termination condition correctly. **You should include the header for this method that shows the method name and signature**.

Comment: I'm assuming the name of the method is `saveLoop`... you should be using `while(File.Exists(/* some filename */){ filename = CreateMuhFilename(); }` completely separate out the logic for creating the filename from that of creating the file.

Comment: Where is `x` defined? Is the whole block named `saveloop()`? Should `x` be used as a part of the file name? (*it is currently not*)

Comment: I'm guessing you're showing us the contents of the `saveloop()` method. If `!File.Exists(path + @"\" + name + ".xlsx")` returns false the first time, it will recurse forever (or until a stack overflow).

Comment: Um it does change name it adds a number to the end of the original file so it looks like  this inside of string *Filepath\8-16-17-0.xlsx and supposed to change it to *Filepath\8-16-17-0-1.xlsx

Comment: @JacobLenertz - no, it does not. Your LoC `File.Exists(path + @"\" + name + ".xlsx"))` does not use the variable `i`.

Comment: awe i see what your saying i cant simply use the excel save as function? to create an entirely new file?

Comment: @JacobLenertz No, you should be using `if (!File.Exists(path + @"\" + name + "-" + t + ".xlsx")` to get the result you're looking for. But still recursion isn't the best solution here.

Comment: You're calling `saveloop()` recursively in your else block and never returning, so you're recursing infinitely.

Comment: @JacobLenertz - maybe. The problem is your code checks if the file exits at the very top, if it does exist it goes into the `else` statement which increments `i` and calls itself again BUT you do not do anything with `i` so it will recurse infinitly.

Comment: Yes! i think you nailed it! I is looking for a file but the file exists so it does increments but then it goes back and i am still looking for the same file. Gosh i feel so stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the code above is failing is because you do not use `i` in the name of the file so you can increment all you want it does not change the name.

You need to abstract the creation of the name of the file from the code that does the writing. Think of it as writing code in blocks of functionality.

```
public static string GetFileName(string path, string name)
{
    var fileName = $@"{path}\{name}.xlsx";
    int i = 0;
    while (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        i++;
        fileName = $@"{path}\{name}({i}).xlsx";
    }
    return fileName;
}


public void saveloop()
{
    var fileName = GetFileName(path, name);
    // use fileName from this point on
}
```